# sdm says the device is already mounted

Tags: loop-device

Ubuntu 23.04, [sdm](https://github.com/gitbls/sdm) v8.6, after rebooting the system I issue:

```
sdm --customize \
    --L10n \
    --apt-dist-upgrade \
    --autologin \
    --hdmi-force-hotplug \
    --journal none \
    --nowait-timesync \
    --ssh service \
    --regen-ssh-host-keys \
    --restart \
    --disable piwiz,bluetooth,swap,triggerhappy \
    --rename-pi user \
    --password-pi mypassword \
    --hotspot hotspot.cfg \
    --loadlocal usb,flashled \
    --plugin apps:"apps=apache2|name=apache" \
    --plugin apps:"apps=curl,php8.1,php8.1-mysql,php-common,php8.1-intl,php8.1-cli,php8.1-common,php8.1-opcache,libapache2-mod-php8.1,php8.1-mbstring,php8.1-xml|name=PHP" \
    --plugin apps:"apps=mariadb-server,mariadb-client,phpmyadmin|name=mariabd" \
    --plugin copyfile:"from=/home/mark/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub|to=/home/user/.ssh|mkdirif" \
    --plugin rxapp \
    --plugin vnc:"realvnc|tigervnc=1280x1024,1920x1080" \       
    /home/Mark/Scaricati/2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64.img
```

and I get this output:

> ? Device   is already mounted

I don't think it's true since in:

```
$ losetup -a
/dev/loop1: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/blender_3949.snap)
/dev/loop19: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20_7.snap)
/dev/loop17: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/inkscape_10542.snap)
/dev/loop8: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_858.snap)
/dev/loop15: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap)
/dev/loop6: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_2015.snap)
/dev/loop23: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_83.snap)
/dev/loop13: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_120.snap)
/dev/loop4: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/code_136.snap)
/dev/loop21: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_19457.snap)
/dev/loop11: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_2916.snap)
/dev/loop2: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/blender_3952.snap)
/dev/loop0: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap)
/dev/loop18: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20_15.snap)
/dev/loop9: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/cups_974.snap)
/dev/loop16: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/inkscape_10539.snap)
/dev/loop7: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_817.snap)
/dev/loop14: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_126.snap)
/dev/loop5: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1974.snap)
/dev/loop22: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_19993.snap)
/dev/loop12: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_2993.snap)
/dev/loop3: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/code_137.snap)
/dev/loop20: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_959.snap)
/dev/loop10: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/cups_980.snap)

$ df -h
File system     Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
tmpfs           6,2G  4,0M    6,2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5  240G   42G    186G  19% /
tmpfs            31G     0     31G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M   20K    5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   38M    219M  15% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme1n1p1   92G   58G     30G  67% /home
tmpfs           6,2G  108K    6,2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

there is no evidence of any `sdm` loop device.
What can cause such a behavior?